# Why won't the lighten and darken method pass information to the toString method for final output?

Tags: java, constructor, tostring

Below is my Java Color class for my intro to Java class. I am attempting to pass the color object created by the lighten and darken method to the toString() method for final output, however every time I attempt to do the output from the toString method is always #000 when it is suppose to be the hex value of the color.

```
public class Color {

    private static int red;
    private static int green;
    private static int blue;

    public Color(int r, int g, int b) {
        r = red;
        g = green;
        b = blue;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String ax = Integer.toHexString(Color.red);
        String bx = Integer.toHexString(Color.green);
        String cx = Integer.toHexString(Color.blue);
        return "#" + ax + bx + cx;
    }

    public static Color dim() {
        int xr = ((red * 80)/100);
        if (xr < 0) {xr = 0;}
        int xg = ((green * 80)/100);
        if (xg < 0) {xg = 0;}
        int xb = ((blue * 80)/100);
        if (xb < 0) {xb = 0;}
        return new Color(xr, xg, xb);
    }

    public static Color lighten() {
        int xr = ((red * 120)/100);
        if (xr > 255) {xr = 255;}
        int xg = ((green * 120)/100);
        if (xg > 255) {xg = 255;}
        int xb = ((blue * 120)/100);
        if (xb > 255) {xb = 255;}
        return new Color(xr, xg, xb);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've shown your `Color` class, but you haven't shown anything calling `lighten` or `darken`. Please provide a [mcve] or it will be hard to help you. If you expect your hex string to always be 6 hex digits though, you need to work out how to do padding...

Comment: Side note that may well be relevant - why are your methods and fields static? That's almost *certainly* not what you want.

Comment: The red, green, and blue fields should not be static and you have the assignments backwards in your constructor. You should be assigning the parameters to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

In java you have Classes and Objects that are instances of those classes. When you declare a field or method as `static` it will belong to the class and not to the instance. So when you call Color.red, you will get the value of the class field which is not instanced.
The best practice in your case would be to remove the `static` from your fields (but keep it on your methods) and create getters and setters instead.
This concept is better explained there : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/fields.html#static-and-non-static-fields

Comment: Additionally, the code of the constructor is wrong. You are assigning the values of the fields to the params